# Copy an entire worksheet to a new worksheet in Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have found similar questions that deal with copying an entire worksheet in one workbook and pasting it to another workbook, but I am interested in simply copying an entire worksheet and pasting it to a new worksheet -- in the same workbook.

I'm in the process of converting a 2003 .xls file to 2010 .xlsm and the old method used for copying and pasting between worksheets doesn't paste with the correct row heights. My initial workaround was to loop through each row and grab the row heights from the worksheet I am copying from, then loop through and insert those values for the row heights in the worksheet I am pasting to, but the problem with this approach is that the sheet contains buttons which generate new rows which changes the row numbering and the format of the sheet is such that all rows cannot just be one width.

What I would really like to be able to do is just simply copy the entire worksheet and paste it. Here is the code from the 2003 version:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").Cells.Copy
newWorksheet.Paste
```

I'm surprised that converting to .xlsm is causing this to break now. Any suggestions or ideas would be great.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It is simpler just to run an exact copy like below to put the copy in as the last sheet

```
Sub Test()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
ws1.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 19):

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").Sheet1.Cells.Copy _
    Destination:=newWorksheet.Cells
```

The above will copy the cells. If you really want to duplicate the entire sheet, then I'd go with [@brettdj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8439771/119775).

Comment: I'd suggest copying the used range in preference to all cells.

Answer (score 8):

```
' Assume that the code name the worksheet is Sheet1

' Copy the sheet using code name and put in the end.
' Note: Using the code name lets the user rename the worksheet without breaking the VBA code
Sheet1.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

' Rename the copied sheet keeping the same name and appending a string " copied"
ActiveSheet.Name = Sheet1.Name & " copied"
```

Answer (score 2):

I really liked @brettdj's code, but then I found that when I added additional code to edit the copy, it overwrote my original sheet instead. I've tweaked his answer so that further code pointed at `ws1` will affect the new sheet rather than the original.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ws1 as Worksheet
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").Copy
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master (2)")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'Make the excel file that runs the software the active workbook
ThisWorkbook.Activate

'The first sheet used as a temporary place to hold the data 
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells.Copy

'Create a new Excel workbook
Dim NewCaseFile As Workbook
Dim strFileName As String

Set NewCaseFile = Workbooks.Add
With NewCaseFile
    Sheets(1).Select
    Cells(1, 1).Select
End With

ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: BTW, you don't need to select the new workbook and sheet to paste, just use `NewCaseFile.Worksheets(1).Paste`.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has, like I do, an Estimating workbook with a default number of visible pricing sheets, a Summary and a larger number of hidden and 'protected' worksheets full of sensitive data but may need to create additional visible worksheets to arrive at a proper price, I have variant of the above responses that creates the said visible worksheets based on a protected hidden "Master".  I have used the code provided by @/jean-fran%c3%a7ois-corbett and @thanos-a in combination with simple VBA as shown below.

Sub sbInsertWorksheetAfter()

```
    'This adds a new visible worksheet after the last visible worksheet

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

    'This copies the content of the HIDDEN "Master" worksheet to the new VISIBLE ActiveSheet just created

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Cells.Copy _
        Destination:=ActiveSheet.Cells

    'This gives the the new ActiveSheet a default name

    With ActiveSheet
        .Name = Sheet12.Name & " copied"
    End With

    'This changes the name of the ActiveSheet to the user's preference

    Dim sheetname As String

    With ActiveSheet
        sheetname = InputBox("Enter name of this Worksheet")
        .Name = sheetname
    End With
```

End Sub