# VBA : Merge certain worksheets in different workbooks into one workbook

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I encounter a problem that I can’t solve. Here it is :

I want to copy certain worksheets contained in certain workbooks and paste it all in a single new workbook.

More specifically, I have a Folder called « Fonds » which contain 20 workbooks, each one having the same structure :
They are all called « 01082014_FONDS », 01082014 changing for each workbook and being a day of the month.
In each of those workbooks, there is a worksheet called « Portfolio » and another one called « Disponibilités ». I wanna copy those 2 worksheets (there are others but I want to copy only those ones) and paste it in a new workbook.

A the end, I have 40 sheets in a single workbooks, called « Portfolio 1 », « Disponibilités 1 », « Portfolio 2 », « Disponibilités 2 »…

Anyone can help me on this ?
Thank you very much !

Comment: Do you have any existing code?

Comment: Not really since I don't really know how to start on this one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do the following in VBA:

1. Loop through files in a folder [Loop through files in a folder using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba)
2. Find if the word "Fonds" is in the file name: [Check if a string contains another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585058/check-if-a-string-contains-another-string)
3. Open the workbook that you find: `Set wb = Workbooks.open(filename)`
4. Loop through the worksheets in the workbook: [Loop through Excel Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422356/excel-macro-loop-through-excel-sheets)
5. Find if the word "Portfolio" or "Disponibilités" is in the worksheet's name: [Check if a string contains another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585058/check-if-a-string-contains-another-string)
6. Rename the worksheet you find: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/72647-any-way-rename-sheet-visual-basic-applications.html
7. Copy the worksheet to the current workbook: [Copy an entire worksheet to a new worksheet in Excel 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439657/copy-an-entire-worksheet-to-a-new-worksheet-in-excel-2010)
8. Close the workbook: `wb.close SaveChanges:=false`

Answer (score 0):

To help you, here is the first point...

first point :

Function s()

```
MyPath = "D:\FOLDER\TEST\*.xls"   ' Set the path.
MyName = Dir(MyPath)   ' Retrieve the first entry.
Do While MyName <> ""   ' Start the loop.
   Call MsgBox(MyName)
   MyName = Dir()   ' Get next entry.
Loop
```

End Function