# ActiveSheet.paste with offset giving error

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I am new to VBA and I was designing a program.  It simply selects Sheet2 and copies something from cell A1.  It then selects Sheet1 and offsets from cell A1 and pastes to the newly selected cell.  The code is as follows.

```
Sub Test()
   Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
   ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Activate
   Selection.Copy
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
   ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Activate
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Activate
   ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

The strange thing is that if I change the line .Offset(1, 1) to .Offset(1) the program will work correctly.  If I do not I get a Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error.

I am aware that there are better ways to go about this than using selections and while those are interesting to me I would also like to know the reason for the problem.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code is not working is due to the the overuse of  the [Range .Activate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221681(v=office.11).aspx). This is different from `.Range.Select` in that it only makes a different cell in the selection the [ActiveCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174738(v=office.11).aspx). If the worksheet's [Selection object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223084(v=office.11).aspx) only encompasses a single cell or a range of cells outside of what you are activating,  then yes you will will select a single cell. If it is within the current worksheet's selected cells the it will only transfer user control to that cell.

Select a range of cells on a worksheet. For the purposes of this example C3:E8. Depending upon how you have selectected the cells, C3 is most likely in a different colour state and holds the [ActiveCell property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174738(v=office.11).aspx) for that worksheet. It will receive any user input.

Now tap <kbd>Enter↵</kbd> a few times. You will see that the 'focus' (aka ActiveCell) changes as you tap the Enter key. While C3:E8 may be the worksheet's [Selection property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa196885(v=office.11).aspx), the worksheet's [ActiveCell property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174738(v=office.11).aspx) changes as you tap <kbd>Enter↵</kbd>.

If you are pasting an unknown number of cells into a target destination, you should pick a single cell in the upper-left corner of where you want the cells to reside. Having a target of multiple cells with one cell somewhere within the range as the active cell will not work unless by circumstance and circumstance is not a reliable programming paradigm.

In short, if you `.Activate` a cell you will only be selecting a single cell if the cell you activate is outside the current selection. If you `.Select` a cell the that is the only one selected and is the active cell on that worksheet. You cannot paste into a range of cells that is a different rows × columns size than the source unless it is a single cell.

Your code should work with a simple modification.

```
Sub Test()
   Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
   ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Activate
   Selection.Copy
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
   ActiveSheet.Range("A1").SELECT   '<~~ this is changed to .Select
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Activate
   ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

However, there may be better ways. Direct Copy and paste is a preferred alternative but if all you want is the [Range.Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) then a direct value transfer is best.

```
'abbreviated Copy and Paste
Sub Test2()
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("A1").Copy _
            Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(1, 1)
    End With
End Sub

'direct value transfer
Sub Test3()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(1, 1)
        .Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value
    End With
End Sub
```

If you do not need to transfer cell formatting, the latter is preferred.

See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you might be having issues it that to perform a pastespecial you should have a cell selected, going through microsofts guide they've outlined it below. Since you are new to VBA it is good to avoid `.activate` its good habit to get into copy/paste without selecting a cell. An example for your code would be:

`Sub Test()
   Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Copy
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(1,1).Paste
End Sub`

[Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835858.aspx)

Comment: Hi I tried this sample code and it doesn't work.  It has a problem with the 2nd line it gives the error "run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method".  Is there a setting I am supposed to have turned on or something?

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler just to run an exact copy like below to put the copy in as the last sheet

```
    Sub Test()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
    ws1.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    End Sub
```

** [Copy an entire worksheet to a new worksheet in Excel 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439657/copy-an-entire-worksheet-to-a-new-worksheet-in-excel-2010)

You can also use the Below
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B10").Copy                                                 Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E1")

```
    'Method 2
    'Copy the data
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B10").Copy
    'Activate the destination worksheet
    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    'Select the target range
    Range("E1").Select
    'Paste in the target destination
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

End Sub

Comment: I believe only Sheet1!B2 was intended to receive the contents and formatting of Sheet1!A1. I don't believe entire worksheets were involved unless the OP neglected to state the [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx).